# Creating a short code with php inside

Tags: shortcode

I am trying to get this code:

```
public function add_request_quote_btn() {
    global $product;
    $product_id = $product->get_id();
    $wc_quote_show_button = get_option('wc_quote_show_button');
    $enable_btn = 'no';
    if($wc_quote_show_button == 'all' || $wc_quote_show_button == '')
        $enable_btn = 'yes';
    elseif($wc_quote_show_button == 'out_stock' && !$product->is_in_stock())
        $enable_btn = 'yes';
    elseif($wc_quote_show_button == 'guest_users' && !is_user_logged_in())
        $enable_btn = 'yes';
    elseif($wc_quote_show_button == 'logged_in_users' && is_user_logged_in())
        $enable_btn = 'yes';
    elseif($wc_quote_show_button == 'specific_products'){
        $wc_quote_products = get_option('wc_quote_products');
        if(!empty($wc_quote_products) && in_array($product_id, $wc_quote_products))
            $enable_btn = 'yes';
    }
        
    
    if($enable_btn == 'yes')
    {
        
        $wc_quote_button_text = get_option('wc_quote_button_text');
        if($wc_quote_button_text == '')
            $wc_quote_button_text = __('Request Quote', 'woocommerce');
        
        echo "<button class="open-wc-quote-form single_add_to_cart_button button alt" data-product="'.$product_id.'">'.$wc_quote_button_text.'</button>";
    }
```

into a shortcode so i can put this button wjere i need it.
Everything i try throws errors or 417 failed expectation.

Could someone help me out?

Thanks
Wayne

Comment: You need to add the actual code you're using to setup the shortcode and the actual text of the error to your question

Answer (score -1):

I stripped out a lot of the code that wouldn't be needed in a shortcode:

```
function sx372821_request_quote_button( $atts = array() ) {
    global $product;

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'button_text'   => get_option( 'wc_quote_button_text' ),
    ), $atts, 'request_quote_button' );

    $product_id = $product->get_id();

    $wc_quote_button_text = esc_html( $atts['button_text'] );

    if ( empty( $wc_quote_button_text ) ) {
        $wc_quote_button_text = esc_html__( 'Request Quote', 'woocommerce' );
    }

    return "<button class=\"open-wc-quote-form single_add_to_cart_button button alt\" data-product=\"{$product_id}\">{$wc_quote_button_text}</button>";
}

add_shortcode( 'request_quote_button', 'sx372821_request_quote_button' );
```

Now you can do:

`[request_quote_button]`

or specify the button text if you want to override the default:

`[request_quote_button button_text="Get a Quote"]`